# Сдвигается кнопка в css

Tags: html, css

Когда текста в кнопке нет, все окей. Но как только добавляю текст, кнопка сдвигается.

```css
.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.cardimage,
.cardimage img {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 140px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

.cardbuttons {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 160px;
  text-align: center;
}

.cardbuttons button {
  width: 99px;
  height: 79px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.cardbuttons button:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='card'>
  <div class='cardimage'>
    <img src='' alt="dddddd" />
  </div>
  <div class='cardbuttons'>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button>f</button>
    <button></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не совсем понятно куда и как сдвигается, приведите пример желаемого поведения.